# How to send auto SMS using ozeki server?

Tags: php

My problem is that I am using a while loop, but only one message gets send. All records are stored in a database. I want to send messages to all numbers that are stored in the database. How can I do that?

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
<?php

$sql   = "select * from subscribe where type ='$cat' and city ='$city'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);

if ($query != null) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $name      = $row['name'];
        $phoneNum  = $row['fone'];
        $condition = 'true';
        $message   = "Hi Now you can buy your product.";
        include('sendsms.php');
        $debug     = true;

        ozekiSend($phoneNum, $message, $debug);
    }
}
?>
```

File: **sendsms.php**

```
<?php
########################################################
# Login information for the SMS Gateway
########################################################

$ozeki_user     = "admin";
$ozeki_password = "abc123";
$ozeki_url      = "http://127.0.0.1:9501/api?";

########################################################
# Functions used to send the SMS message
########################################################

function httpRequest($url)
{
    $pattern = "/http...([0-9a-zA-Z-.]*).([0-9]*).(.*)/";
    preg_match($pattern, $url, $args);
    $in      = "";
    $fp      = fsockopen("$args[1]", $args[2], $errno, $errstr, 30);
    if (!$fp) {
        return("$errstr ($errno)");
    } else {
        $out = "GET /$args[3] HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        $out .= "Host: $args[1]:$args[2]\r\n";
        $out .= "User-agent: Ozeki PHP client\r\n";
        $out .= "Accept: */*\r\n";
        $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";

        fwrite($fp, $out);
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $in.=fgets($fp, 128);
        }
    }
    fclose($fp);
    return($in);
}

function ozekiSend($phone, $msg, $debug = false)
{
    global $ozeki_user, $ozeki_password, $ozeki_url;

    $url = 'username=' . $ozeki_user;
    $url.= '&password=' . $ozeki_password;
    $url.= '&action=sendmessage';
    $url.= '&messagetype=SMS:TEXT';
    $url.= '&recipient=' . urlencode($phone);
    $url.= '&messagedata=' . urlencode($msg);

    $urltouse = $ozeki_url . $url;
    if ($debug) {
        echo "Request: <br>$urltouse<br><br>";
    }

    //Open the URL to send the message
    $response = httpRequest($urltouse);
    if ($debug) {
        echo "Response: <br><pre>" .
        str_replace(array("<", ">"), array("&lt;", "&gt;"), $response) .
        "</pre><br>";
    }

    return($response);
}

########################################################
# GET data from sendsms.html
########################################################

$phonenum = $_POST['recipient']; //here how i receive data from while loop???//
$message  = $_POST['message'];
$debug    = true;

ozekiSend($phonenum, $message, $debug);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i moved things around a bit.

Notes:

- sendsms.php was included over and over again, include it once at the top of the file
- but here i remove the include completly, by merging both files together
- the while loop contains $name. it's unused. because ozekiSend() only accepts 3 parameters: phone number, message and debug. i changed it, so the
  name is used in the message.

File: **multi_sms_send.php**

```
<?php   
$sql   = "select * from subscribe where type ='$cat' and city ='$city'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);

if ($query != null) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $name      = $row['name'];

        $phoneNum  = $row['fone'];
        $message   = "Hi ".$name.", now you can buy your product.";

        ozekiSend($phoneNum, $message);

        // for debugging, try the following line
        //echo ozekiSend($phoneNum, $message, true);
    }
}

########################################################
# Login information for the SMS Gateway
########################################################

$ozeki_user     = "admin";
$ozeki_password = "abc123";
$ozeki_url      = "http://127.0.0.1:9501/api?";

########################################################
# Functions used to send the SMS message
########################################################

function httpRequest($url)
{
    $pattern = "/http...([0-9a-zA-Z-.]*).([0-9]*).(.*)/";
    preg_match($pattern, $url, $args);
    $in      = "";
    $fp      = fsockopen("$args[1]", $args[2], $errno, $errstr, 30);
    if (!$fp) {
        return("$errstr ($errno)");
    } else {
        $out = "GET /$args[3] HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        $out .= "Host: $args[1]:$args[2]\r\n";
        $out .= "User-agent: Ozeki PHP client\r\n";
        $out .= "Accept: */*\r\n";
        $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";

        fwrite($fp, $out);
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $in.=fgets($fp, 128);
        }
    }
    fclose($fp);
    return($in);
}

function ozekiSend($phone, $msg, $debug = false)
{
    global $ozeki_user, $ozeki_password, $ozeki_url;

    $url = 'username=' . $ozeki_user;
    $url.= '&password=' . $ozeki_password;
    $url.= '&action=sendmessage';
    $url.= '&messagetype=SMS:TEXT';
    $url.= '&recipient=' . urlencode($phone);
    $url.= '&messagedata=' . urlencode($msg);

    $urltouse = $ozeki_url . $url;
    if ($debug === true) {
        echo "Request: <br>$urltouse<br><br>";
    }

    //Open the URL to send the message
    $response = httpRequest($urltouse);
    if ($debug === true) {
        echo "Response: <br><pre>" .
        str_replace(array("<", ">"), array("&lt;", "&gt;"), $response) .
        "</pre><br>";
    }

    return($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: this error is occur ?? now??

Fatal error: Call to undefined function ozekisend() in C:\xampp\htdocs\funsmss\location\post.php on line 72

Comment: you have not used my file. ozekiSend() is not on line 72. The error means that your ozekiSend() function is not available, because the include statement is wrong.

Comment: how to use your file? in my code  i am using your code not your file

Comment: Sure this is my code :) But.. in my code the call to ozekiSend() is not on line 72..it's on line 12. So you are copy pasting stuff into your own code.. wihtout understanding what you actually do. Re-read what i have written above: the function is not found, because the include is not made. My code works without an include statement, because everything is merged in one file.

Comment: You also asked in a comment `//here how i receive data from while loop???//`.  You get the response from the server, by `echo ozekiSend($phoneNum, $message, true);`. I've added that already, it's commented out.

Comment: how to use my file? simply copy and paste the stuff into a new php file and adjust the `$ozeki_user` and `$ozeki_password`credentials and then (i hope) it should work :) If not we will figure it out...

Comment: yes sir i completely understand your code error in my code on line 72 because according to my sequence of line but generally error in this function on line 12 its ozekiSend($phoneNum, $message); this function not working

Comment: So the function itself is not working? Try it with `echo ozekiSend($phoneNum, $message, true);` to get the debug output of the function. Please post the PHP error again.

Comment: hi now i am using your code as external file and include this file in my code but when i execute then all numbers retrieve from database but message not sent these error is occur.

Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to :0 (Failed to parse address "") in C:\xampp\htdocs\funsmss\location\sendsms.php

Failed to parse address "" (0)

Comment: (General message to readers: the problem from the OP in the comments has [been moved to a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23853763/472495)).

Comment: This is really frusting on SO. I get a feeling that people just copy pasting stuff into SO and say: "Hey, i'd like to have X. Not working. Help, Please." This Q is a typical example for that. The original code comes from http://www.ozekisms.com/php-sms-api-asp-sms-api/index_p_php_q_ow_page_number_e_327opt.html The only addition is the MySQL piece of code, which he asked for in another SO question. Next piece of code, comes from me. The fix for preg_match() comes in another Q.... Let other people do the work - learn nothing.

Comment: @user3651840: don't take it personally, but Jens-André is right about excessive demands for help. Some comments threads have been known to go on for 30, 40 or 50 rounds, and the poor answerer is left feeling they are doing a good deal of someone else's work for very little reward. It is a really big problem here, and discourages people from helping. I think you commented earlier to say your problem is urgent (now deleted by a moderator at my request) - it is worth remembering that people helping you are volunteers, and will help you as and when they wish.

Comment: @user3651840: A good rule of thumb is, when you get an answer, try applying it to your situation without any further help, at least to start with. Consider it a set of hints for you to do further research on. Then, if you are really are still stuck, add a comment and be really detailed as to what the new, connected problem is. Be willing to upvote early, too, to thank the person helping you.

Comment: (If you don't mind, please +1 or accept this answer - code rewrites are quite rare here, so Jens has certainly been very helpful).