# How to send SMS on multiple numbers stored in database

Tags: php

This is my code and I am using as external file include in my code as external file. When new user post this code is run but not sent message on all numbers that stored in      database:

Error is:

> Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to :0
>
> (Failed to   parse  address "") in C:\xampp\htdocs\funsmss\location\sendsms.php
>   Failed to parse address "" (0)

Here's the code:

```
    <?php   
     $sql   = "select * from subscribe where type ='$cat' and city ='$city'";
     $query = mysql_query($sql);

  if ($query != null) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $name      = $row['name'];

    $phoneNum  = $row['fone'];
    $message   = "Hi ".$name.", now you can buy your product.";

    ozekiSend($phoneNum, $message);

    // for debugging, try the following line
    //echo ozekiSend($phoneNum, $message, true);
     }
   }

 ########################################################
 # Login information for the SMS Gateway
 ########################################################

 $ozeki_user     = "admin";
 $ozeki_password = "abc123";
 $ozeki_url      = "http://127.0.0.1:9501/api?";

 ########################################################
 # Functions used to send the SMS message
 ########################################################

  function httpRequest($url)
 {
$pattern = "/http...([0-9a-zA-Z-.]*).([0-9]*).(.*)/";
preg_match($pattern, $url, $args);
$in      = "";
$fp      = fsockopen("$args[1]", $args[2], $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    return("$errstr ($errno)");
} else {
    $out = "GET /$args[3] HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: $args[1]:$args[2]\r\n";
    $out .= "User-agent: Ozeki PHP client\r\n";
    $out .= "Accept: */*\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";

    fwrite($fp, $out);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $in.=fgets($fp, 128);
    }
    }
    fclose($fp);
     return($in);
  }

  function ozekiSend($phone, $msg, $debug = false)
  {
 global $ozeki_user, $ozeki_password, $ozeki_url;

$url = 'username=' . $ozeki_user;
$url.= '&password=' . $ozeki_password;
$url.= '&action=sendmessage';
$url.= '&messagetype=SMS:TEXT';
$url.= '&recipient=' . urlencode($phone);
$url.= '&messagedata=' . urlencode($msg);

$urltouse = $ozeki_url . $url;
if ($debug === true) {
    echo "Request: <br>$urltouse<br><br>";
}

//Open the URL to send the message
$response = httpRequest($urltouse);
if ($debug === true) {
    echo "Response: <br><pre>" .
    str_replace(array("<", ">"), array("&lt;", "&gt;"), $response) .
    "</pre><br>";
}

return($response);
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: try `fsockopen($args[1].':'.$args[2]);`

Comment: Is `$args[1]` actually populated? If it is, remove the `"` quote marks from either side in the `fsockopen` line, you don't need them.

Comment: no its not working error is fail to parse address

Comment: Err, what's the address, then?

Comment: `$pattern` is very bad. Try this `'/http\:\/\/([\w\-\.]+)(\:[0-9]+)?(\/\S*)?/i';`

Comment: Note to readers: a related question from the OP is here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23843985/472495. I think this new question came out of a conversation with someone on an answer on the earlier question. Not sure if it is a dup.